# Loading values from environment variables in my React application not working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In my React app (using create react app) I have a Constants.js file that has the folowing constants:

```
export const API_ROOT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ROOT || 'http://www.example.com.com:4000/api';
export const APP_ROOT = process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ROOT || 'http://app.example.com:3001';
```

For some reason this is not being picked up on my server even though I have defined the ENV variables on the server. I changed the values around just to see where the values are being picked up from.

```
API_ROOT=http://dev.example.com/api
APP_ROOT=http://app.example.com
REACT_APP_API_ROOT=http://www.example.com:3002/api
REACT_APP_APP_ROOT=http://app.example.com:3002
```

I wasn't sure of the naming convention so I defined all 4 of the above.
When I push to my server I still see the API_ROOT and APP_ROOT values being the defaults i.e. not from the ENV variable:

```
  http://www.example.com.com:4000/api
  http://app.example.com:3001
```

I did verify by logging into the server and verifying the ENV variables existed:

```
echo $API_ROOT
echo $REACT_APP_API_ROOT
```

What am I doing wrong in terms of getting the values from ENV variables?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.env` is a global Object provided by your environment through NodeJs. Because we don't have NodeJS in browser, it won't understand `process.env.API_ROOT`. You init your app using `react-create-app` with `webpack` included by default, so I recommend you to use  `.env` file to set environment variables by using [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv).

**Note**: `dotenv` is included in `create-react-app` `v0.2.3` and higher

1. Create `.env` file include

   ```
   API_ROOT=http://dev.example.com/api
   APP_ROOT=http://app.example.com
   REACT_APP_API_ROOT=http://www.example.com:3002/api
   REACT_APP_APP_ROOT=http://app.example.com:3002
   ```
2. Config webpack:

   ```
   const webpack = require('webpack');
   const dotenv = require('dotenv');

   module.exports = () => {
     // call dotenv and it will return an Object with a parsed key 
     const env = dotenv.config().parsed;

     // reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
     const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
       prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
       return prev;
     }, {});

     return {
       plugins: [
         new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
       ]
     };
   ```

Reference:

- https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5
- https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

Hope this will help.

Comment: when I run ```yarn run build``` will that use the node env = production?  I want to have DEV and PROD environment variables to be different.

Comment: You can create 2 different files: `.env` (contains all the environment variables for production), `.env.development` (contains all the environment variables for development). It's easy to use, please take a look at the Reference in my answer for more details.

Comment: @Blankman I have updated my answer, `dotenv` is included in `create-react-app` v0.2.3 and higher, document goes here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env